Is it possible to configure firebase database connection settings within the application in flutter? If so, how can I do it?
Is it possible to configure firebase database connection settings within the application in flutter? If so, how can I do it?
void main() async{
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
final settingsController = Get.put(SettingsController());
await  settingsController.loadSettings();`
await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: settingsController.firebaseOptions,
);
runApp(const MyApp());
}


class SettingsController extends GetxController {
var apiKey = ''.obs;
var projectId = ''.obs;
var messagingSenderId = ''.obs;
var appId = ''.obs;

@override
void onInit() {
super.onInit();
loadSettings();
}

Future <void> loadSettings() async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
apiKey.value = prefs.getString('apiKey') ?? '';
projectId.value = prefs.getString('projectId') ?? '';
messagingSenderId.value = prefs.getString('messagingSenderId') ?? '';
appId.value = prefs.getString('appId') ?? '';
}

Future <void> saveSettings() async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setString('apiKey', apiKey.value);
await prefs.setString('projectId', projectId.value);
await prefs.setString('messagingSenderId', messagingSenderId.value);
await prefs.setString('appId', appId.value);

}

FirebaseOptions get firebaseOptions => FirebaseOptions(
apiKey: apiKey.value,
projectId: projectId.value,
messagingSenderId: messagingSenderId.value,
appId: appId.value,
);
}

I usually get this error when trying to do this
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [core/duplicate-app] A Firebase App named "[DEFAULT]" already exists
Actually, I had a goal of taking the user's information and disabling the identification in Firebase Options. Since I do not have any information, I am asking you, if it does not work, I will continue my project with SQLite.

class DefaultFirebaseOptions {
    static FirebaseOptions get currentPlatform {
        if (kIsWeb) {
          throw UnsupportedError(
            'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for web - '
                'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
          );
        }
        
        switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
            case TargetPlatform.android:
                return android;
            case TargetPlatform.iOS:
                return ios;
            case TargetPlatform.macOS:
                throw UnsupportedError(
                    'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for macos - '
                    'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
                );
            case TargetPlatform.windows:
                throw UnsupportedError(
                    'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for windows - '
                    'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
                );
            case TargetPlatform.linux:
                throw UnsupportedError(
                    'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for linux - '
                    'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
                );
            default:
                throw UnsupportedError(
                    'DefaultFirebaseOptions are not supported for this platform.',
                );
        }
    }
    //----------try with intial value Of firebase Configuration

--------      
    static const FirebaseOptions android = FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: '',
        appId: '',
        messagingSenderId: '',
        projectId: '',
        storageBucket: '',
    );
    
    static const FirebaseOptions ios = FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: '',
        appId: '',
        messagingSenderId: '',
        projectId: '',
        storageBucket: '',
        iosBundleId: '',
    );
}

in Main .dart
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
// Sets the preferred orientation to portrait mode
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);

I have done this multiple times and it's working fine
